# Need to access session-timeout value in JSP

Tags: jsp, session, timeout, web.xml

I have a standard Tomcat/Spring application, with session timeout configured in web.xml :

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I need to access the timeout setting in a JSP:

```
Properties.prototype.setProperty({ 
    'sessionTimeOut' : "<c:out value='${session.sessionTimeOutInterval}'/>",
});
```

Any ideas on how to do that?
It is possible to add a filter that sets session timeout interval as an attribute:

```
session.setAttribute("sessionTimeOutInterval", session.getMaxInactiveInterval());
```

But I'd rather avoid adding a filter.

What would be a better way of making this value available in the JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}
```